# How to set initial value for UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have a switch called `soundSwitch`, I'm saving the state of the button using a `UserDefault` as such:

```swift
@IBAction func soundsChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    if soundSwitch.on {
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "SoundActive")
        print("Sound ON")
    } else {
        defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "SoundActive")
        print("Sound OFF")
    }
}
```

Currently, the actual default value is initially false when the user first launches the application.

How can I implement the defaults to be true if the user launches the app and they haven't been configured yet.

I've seen methods in Objective-C, but nothing in Swift. From what I've seen you can do it in the app delegate somehow, or in a plist file. How do I do either of those ones?

Comment: In your appDelegate you can check if the valueForKey is null.  If it is null you can set it to boolean true

Comment: see : http://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/05/save-data-using-nsuserdefaults-in-swift.html

Answer (score 81):

**Swift 3 syntax example**

Register a boolean default value:

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["SoundActive" : true])
```

And to **get** the value:

```
UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SoundActive")
```

Sidenote: Although the above code will return true, note that the value isn't actually written to disk until you **set** it:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "SoundActive")
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the value isn't actually written to disk until you set it`? Does this mean that, should I never set the default and remove the registration from the `AppDelegate` in future versions, the key wouldn't retrieve `true` because it was never manually set?

Comment: @TomQDDRS that's correct. Quoting https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuserdefaults/1417065-registerdefaults?language=objc: "The contents of the registration domain are not written to disk; you need to call this method each time your application starts."

Answer (score 33):

Add this to your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method from the AppDelegate. As some others pointed out try not to abuse by putting everything in this method.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    /// Here you can give default values to your UserDefault keys
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
        "SoundActive": true,
        "someOtherKey": "Some Message"
        ])
}
```

Comment: Well, the `register` method. Thanks  

Comment: This is tedious. they should have provided a way for us to set a default value when retrieving instead of having to register everything.

Answer (score 20):

**Swift 4**

I prefer to implement a function similar to `UserDefaults.string(forKey: )` which returns `nil` if the value is not set. Combined with the ?? operator, you don't need to have any default values written to disk unless you explicitly set them later.

```
extension UserDefaults {

    public func optionalInt(forKey defaultName: String) -> Int? {
        let defaults = self
        if let value = defaults.value(forKey: defaultName) {
            return value as? Int
        }
        return nil
    }

    public func optionalBool(forKey defaultName: String) -> Bool? {
        let defaults = self
        if let value = defaults.value(forKey: defaultName) {
            return value as? Bool
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then you can retrieve your default values as follows

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let userName = defaults.string(forKey: "Username") ?? "Happy"
let userAge = defaults.optionalInt(forKey: "Age") ?? 21
let isSmart = defaults.optionalBool(forKey: "Smart") ?? true
```

Comment: Best! this is more convenient than registering everything.

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)`. That is a carryover from key-value coding. Use the proper `UserDefaults` API - `object(forKey:)`.

Answer (score 9):

**Using "registerDefaults" you can set Default value of NSUserDefaults**

```
let userDefaultsDefaults = [
            "SoundActive" : true
        ]

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(userDefaultsDefaults)
```

**Note: write this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, so default value is set.**

**write below code where you want to check**

```
 let onoroff = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("SoundActive") as! Bool!

 if (onoroff != nil && onoroff == false)
 {
    self.checkForAgreement()
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing swift or app delegate specific.

Initial defaults are set by calling `registerDefaults:` on the `standardUserDefaults` instance.

You can make this call multiple times and I'd recommend that you don't do it in the app delegate, instead register appropriate details at appropriate times in the app, so if you have 1 view controller / subsystem which uses certain defaults values then register the default values as part of the initialisation if that code.

Only if you have something which is used by multiple different parts of the code should you consider doing that in the app delegate, and then only if you don't have some other appropriate controller in which to do it.

Comment: Why would't you do it in the app delegate?

Comment: because the app delegate is there for a specific purpose, and arbitrary user defaults registration is not part of that purpose @simpleBob - being the delegate of the application and handling application level events is, nothing else

Comment: But user defaults registration should be done before anything else, that's why `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` would be a rather obvious place and it is where it is found in most projects. Also, I think it is better to have all defaults in one place than having multiple `registerDefaults` across the whole project.

Comment: it should be done before it is required, and it should be done in a sensible place. sure you can do it in the app delegate, but that is not the purpose of the app delegate, it's just easy and that's why most people do it. @simpleBob

Comment: I think the problem of registering the default when you need them is that someone may need it even earlier and forget to move the registering.

Answer (score 4):

```
func lastStatus() -> Bool {
    let defaultValue = true
    if let value = default.valueForKey("SoundActive") {
        // then use it
        return value as? Bool ?? defaultValue
    } else {
        // oh, no value?
        return defaultValue
    }
}
```

I think this is best way of using it. Also `register(defaults:)` will help, but in documentation Apple suggest to using it as `fallback`, like separating situation of `no value` and `default value`. Depend on your need.

Comment: Do not use `valueForKey` or `setValue:forKey:` with `UserDefaults`. That is for KVC and comes from `NSObject`. `UserDefaults` provides `objectForKey` and `set:forKey:`.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5** — You can encapsulate all of your `UserDefaults` logic into a property that automatically registers the application default and saves any updates back into the user defaults dictionary. This is especially convenient if other parts of the app (besides the switch control) also read or change this state.

This should either be a static property or used on a singleton preferences object, so that the initializer is only called once per app load. The first closure runs once when the object is initialized. The `didSet` block automatically updates `UserDefaults` any time the property is set.

```
static var soundIsActive: Bool = { // property initializer runs once
    // Register the app default:
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["SoundActive" : true])
    
    // Initialize the property with the current user default:
    return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SoundActive")
}()
{
    didSet {
        // Update user default when the variable is set:
        UserDefaults.standard.set(soundIsActive, forKey: "SoundActive")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a clumsy way. Just make `soundIsActive` a full blown computed property where `get` calls `return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "SoundActive")` and `set` calls `UserDefaults.standard.set(soundIsActive, forKey: "SoundActive")`. It's also far from ideal to call `register` every time the getter is accessed.

Comment: @HangarRash The first closure is a property initializer, not a getter. This is even more efficient than your proposal because the implicit getter does not need to access `UserDefaults` at all. However, it's true that if the app initializes multiple objects with this property, `register` should be moved into a static initializer.

Comment: But your initializer does access UserDefaults. Also, while unlikely, if any other code update UserDefaults for that key, your code could return an outdated value. Keep in mind that UseDefaults is just an in-memory dictionary backed by a plist file. You code is trying to optimize something that is already optimized.

Comment: I've edited the answer to clarify. The getter here is generated by the compiler and does not access `UserDefaults` at all. It's a fair point that this is a small optimization, and requires that other parts of the code not change the same user default (which is good practice anyway). I still think this approach is reasonable, and generalizable to other storage methods that may not be as dependably fast as `UserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

Scalar types such as Bool, Int, Double will give a default value.  To get an optional use object.

You can try this.  Can also add a default value as in the second case below:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    
    private enum Keys {
        static let soundActiveOptional = "soundActiveOptional"
        static let soundActiveDefaultTrue = "soundActiveDefaultTrue"
        static let doubleValue = "doubleValue"
    }
    
    var soundActiveOptional: Bool? {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Keys.soundActiveOptional) as? Bool
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: Keys.soundActiveOptional)
        }
    }
    
    var soundActiveDefaultTrue: Bool {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Keys.soundActiveDefaultTrue) as? Bool ?? true
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: Keys.soundActiveDefaultTrue)
        }
    }
    
    var doubleValue: Double {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Keys.doubleValue) as? Double ?? 0.1
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: Keys.doubleValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the closest answer to what I like to do. (Although for me it's usually in an object for this purpose, and not an extension on UserDefaults, although that's a fine way to go too.)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it this way, put this in the AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if defaults.valueForKey("SoundActive") == nil {
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "SoundActive")
    }
```

If it is just used in the one viewcontroller, consider putting the code in the viewDidLoad method instead!

Comment: I don't think it's a good way, because every time I launched the app, it would  run these codes. But in fact, it's only needed at first time.

Comment: OK, you edit it. But I think the best place is when you use the value of "SoundActive", if nil then true.

Comment: Do not use `valueForKey` or `setValue:forKey:` with `UserDefaults`. That is for KVC and comes from `NSObject`. `UserDefaults` provides `objectForKey` and `set:forKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

Generic version of how to set a default value:

```
enum UserDefaultsKeys: String {
    case username = "kUsername"
}

extension UserDefaults {
    func optionalValue<T>(forKey key: UserDefaultsKeys) -> T? {
        if let value = self.value(forKey: key.rawValue) {
            return value as? T
        }
        return nil
    }
}

let username = defaults.optionalValue(forKey: .username) ?? ""
```

Comment: Do not use `valueForKey` or `setValue:forKey:` with `UserDefaults`. That is for KVC and comes from `NSObject`. `UserDefaults` provides `objectForKey` and `set:forKey:`.

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 5 Update**

Set the boolean in your "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" in your AppDelegate like so...

```
//Assumiing you have made a singleton for Userdefaults
public let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        defaults.set(true, forKey: "SoundActive")
        //boiler plate code ...
    }
```