# How to get a default value on nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I want to check if there is a value on a certain variable. If there isn't I want to return a default value. How is the best pratice of doing this?

I would like to do something like:

```
let defaults = Userdefaults()
if let name = defaults.string(foKey "name") { 
    return name 
} else {
    return "john"
}
```

Comment: There's also `UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults:)`. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37830558/2227743.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this..

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let name = defaults.string(foKey "name") ?? "john"
```

`??` in Swift is called [The nil-coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72)

Comment: You should probably be using the shared `UserDefaults.standard` instance instead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even notice that

Answer (score 3):

```
return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name") ?? "john"
```