# iOS mobile application first ever app launch detect

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults, ios-lifecycle

I was trying to initiate an integer value in **UserDefaults**. But I want to do this operation once. At the first launch.

```
func application(_: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions _: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UserDefaults.standard.set(-1, forKey: Constant.shared.empId)
       return true
    }
```

I tried this the above way. But **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** is calling every time I launch the app. is there any function that is called once during the app's whole life cycle?

Comment: You can check whether the value exists (means launched before), before you assign the value for the first time.

Comment: ugh! I think so. Let me try.

Comment: Thanks It worked. But I wonder, there is no such function?

Comment: Apparently there is no such function in the app lifecycle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift - How to set initial value for NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830558/swift-how-to-set-initial-value-for-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can check whether userDefault contains any value or not. If it doesn't have any value, then you can set it. Following code may help you.

```
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Constant.shared.empId) != nil {
            
    print("UserDefaults has a value")
}
else {
    print("UserDefaults doesn't have a value")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(-1, forKey: Constant.shared.empId)
}
```

Comment: While this may work, it is far from the best solution. The other answer about registering a default is a much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need call:

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(
  defaults: {
    Constant.shared.empId: -1
  }
)
```

It will be called every time on app launch, but will not override value set with `set` method.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this code would replace the OP's existing `UserDefaults` code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.